How can I detect and notify users about active VPN connections, and is it possible to close all VPNs from an Android app?
I'm working on an Android app and need to:

Detect when a VPN connection is active.
Notify users that certain
features may not work with VPNs.
Understand if it’s possible to programmatically close
all active VPN connections from my app.

Is there any way to achieve these goals using Android APIs or other methods?

Detect when a VPN connection is active.
Using this snippet you can detect if user is using a VPN connection:
fun Context.isVpnOn(): Boolean {
    val connectivityManager = getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
    val activeNetwork: Network? = connectivityManager.activeNetwork
    val caps: NetworkCapabilities? = connectivityManager.getNetworkCapabilities(activeNetwork)
    return caps?.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN) ?: false
}

I wrote it as an  extension function so you can use it as bellow:
val isVpnOn = context.isVpnOn()
First, we access to device connectivity manager, then we fetch the active network (which can be null if there is no network connection), after that we get  properties and capabilities of the specified network using getNetworkCapabilities.
Finally, we check if the caps (if it's not null) includes the VPN transport capability by calling hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_VPN).
Notify users that certain features may not work with VPNs.
You can use the boolean value of isVpnOn maybe as a mutableState to show the dialog (xml or compose) and notify user that certain features may not work with VPNs.
Understand if it’s possible to programmatically close all active VPN connections from my app.
As I know, Android does not provide APIs to control the VPN state of system or another app.
Hope this has been helpful, dear Vahid .
